# Using With[] vs. Using a Pure Function for Constants

Tags: functions, performance-tuning, scoping, memory, timing

There are many cases where I am conflicted over using `With[]` versus using pure functions when dealing with constants, knowing the output is the same either way. For example, consider

```
f1[input_] := With[{const = g[input]},h[const]]

f2[input_] := h[#] &@g[input]
```

where `g` and `h` are complicated functions defined inline – not defined elsewhere using set delayed.

Of course, the output is the same...

```
f1[3]
(*h[g[3]]*)

f2[3]
(*h[g[3]]*)
```

1. Is there a general rule about which paradigm is faster or uses less memory?
2. Are there any general major considerations I should be making in determining when to use one over the other?

Comment: Why not simply writing: `f[g[input]]` ? Or the same more cryptical: `(f@*g)[x]`

Comment: @DanielHuber I am trying to be as pure as possible, so I mean to have `g` and `h` be inline. This usually makes for better performance. Also, doing as you suggest is messy when `h` refers to its input many times. (I am a bit confused though. It seems you are using `f` the way I am using `h`.)

Comment: MMA evaluates function arguments before a function sees it. So, even if h refers to its input many times, this input is only evaluated once. Sorry, no need for confusion, I simply picked some characters, use h instead of f.

Comment: @DanielHuber But `h` is inline. So what I mean is that `h[g[input]]` is literally, something like `g[input]^g[input]+Range[1,g[input]`, not defined elsewhere with set delayed. In this example, `g[input]` is evaluated 3 times.

Comment: Would you not, in this case, calculate g[input] only once and store it in a variable?

Comment: That's essentially what I'm asking, but treating `g[input]` as a constant, not a variable. So I'm asking which is better optimized for calculating `g[input]` only once and storing it as a constant to be used many times by some complicated inline function `h`.

Comment: I do not see  the difference between a constant that is calculated at runtime  and a variable?

Comment: Variables can change during runtime, constants can't. I would not be able to use `With[]`, I would have to use `Module[]`, which I'm not interested in. In my function `f1[]`, I have `const = g[input]`, and the value of `const` is not changed given `input`. If I used `Module[]` instead, the value of `const` could change given `input`.

Comment: I've never noticed a difference in speed (which I've tested) or memory (which I haven't). The main differences are that the functional way is usually shorter, but with `With` I can use a variable name to help me remember what it stands for as well as break up a really long composition of operations into pieces. Generally speaking, readibility is worth valuing over insignificant speed advantages.

Answer (score 1):

You have several choices with variations:

```
With[{a = (g1[i]; g2[i])}, h1[a]; h2[a]]
(g1[i]; g2[i]) // Function[i, h1[i]; h2[i]]
Function[i, h1[i]; h2[i]][g1[i]; g2[i]]
(h1[#]; h2[#]) & [g1[i]; g2[i]]
(g1[i]; g2[i]) // (h1[#]; h2[#]) &
```

You asked:

> 1. Is there a general rule about which paradigm is faster or uses less memory?

I really doubt there is much difference in those two areas.

> 2. Are there any general major considerations I should be making in determining when to use one over the other?

They do essentially the same thing. It is more a matter of preference or style.